# Make my android app appear in the share list

Tags: android, android-intent, share, intentfilter

How do i make my application appear here? :

[image]

some informations led me to put this code on my `Manifest` (**See code below**) but it doesn't work. The thing is if i want to share an image from my gallery,  i want to see my app on the list of app on the share list. Any pointers? please help.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.my.package.MyIntent"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ALL_APPS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this way

```
       <activity
        android:name="yourActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="test">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

For more information go to [Receiving Simple Data from Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html) and [Sending Simple Data to Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

Comment: @GreenFox so finally it's working ha!

Comment: thanks a lot sir its working.

Comment: But how to receive data like image and videos, I tried intent.getStringExtra() but its showing "" .

Answer (score 3):

[Intent Filters - Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)
Information:

> Note: In order to receive implicit intents, you must include the
>   CATEGORY_DEFAULT category in the intent filter. The methods
>   startActivity() and startActivityForResult() treat all intents as if
>   they declared the CATEGORY_DEFAULT category. If you do not declare
>   this category in your intent filter, no implicit intents will resolve
>   to your activity.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```