# Share Button in Android Gallery

Tags: android, android-studio

First off, I want to say that I'm a really inexperienced android programmer. I've never worked with android studio but I've decided to learn. I need to complete my final course project which is an android app that allows users to search and share their experiences with the world! 
In the android gallery **I want to add to that "Share" button, my app, which, when clicked, would redirect the user to the "Profile Fragment" with a button saying "Share to the world!"**. I know that this is possible as I have already seen some questions like this. The problem is, as I said, I am a little noob in this android programming. Can someone explain how can I resolve my problem is some detailed way?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
This is my **manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        />
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />




</application>
```

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424088/make-my-android-app-appear-in-the-share-list

Comment: Hey! I've tried to use that but I had no success. Where do I put that code?
Should it be
 
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

here?
Please, see my edited post :)

Comment: to whichever activity you add this intent filter, that activity will receive the data, since you have added this to the login activity, you must handle the intent in login activity

Comment: The problem is when I put that inside my login activity, every time I try to run it gets an error:


10:35 Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: C:\Users\asus\.android\avd\Pixel_XL_API_25.avd/userdata.img
 
Does this have something to do it that?

Comment: This doesnot seem to be related with that, paste your entire logcat

Comment: Hm, I've fixed it ahah Now it displays in the Gallery as it should. But when I click it it says that "Couldn't launch your app"

Comment: Again the logcats would help to proceed

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ybnigw3L Here is my logcat