# Setting my app as a sharing target (Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm looking for a way to enable my users to send images to my app via sharing (On android).

My main goal right now is to get my app on the "share to" tab when pressing the share button in the gallery, and storing the shared picture(or a link to the picture).

Comment: **[Receiving simple data from other apps](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive)**

Comment: I'm very new to Xamarin could you maybe walk me through how to implement this tutorial to my app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found my answer using a android studio instead of xamarin, as it was giving me a lot of problems.
If you have the same problem yourself, you should follow Arvindraja answer, please do not that his answer will only make your app appear in the share menu but the data you will share to it will not be saved anywhere, for that you will need additional code.

Comment: Thats not an answer andriod studio and Xamrain to very different products

Answer (score 1):

To have your project in share list you need to manipulate your menifest file

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true" 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<activity android:name=".MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

    </application>
```

& for more information on this you can visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424088/make-my-android-app-appear-in-the-share-list) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095122/how-to-make-my-android-app-appear-in-the-share-list-of-another-specific-app)

In those links you might get things in more precise way.
Good luck.

Comment: Im getting an error with this code, it says "expecting '>'" should I have put it in android-manifest(the one under properties) ?

Comment: It didn't work, this is my AndroidManifest.xml file, perhaps you can see what I did wrong https://pastebin.com/7gSuh3qV

Comment: @Arel Check my updated answer. You need to keep activity tag Inside Application tag & need to specify activity name to.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem
After some effort, I found this solution
Remove this from the manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" >
   .....
</activity>
```

And replace it with this code in the activity you want to run directly

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.SEND" }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeTypes = new[] { "text/plain" })]
```

my best wishes