# How do I listen in Xamarin to events where the user wants to open a file with a certain extension?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My app is programmed in Xamarin and I want allow the user to open `pdf` in my app.

Currently, in Android when the user clicks on an attachment in Gmail that has a `PDF there's a dialog titled`Complete the action using`that allows the user to choose an app with which the phone opens the`PDF` file. How do I get listed in that dialog via Xamarin (ideally in a way that also works on other platforms)?

Comment: There you go ;)
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465429/register-to-be-default-app-for-custom-file-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465429/register-to-be-default-app-for-custom-file-type)

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51556376/setting-my-app-as-a-sharing-target-xamarin/51560082#51560082

Answer (score 2):

You have to update your manifest to tell Android that you can handle pdf files.

```
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I understand how I would mark an activity this way in standard Android but I'm unsure how it works in Xamarin given Xamarin seems to automatically generate the code for the activities in the manifest. 
Can you write more about how this is supposed to look in Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class derived from `Activity`. You'll have to annotate this class with the `ActivityAttribute` as well as th `IntentFilterAttribute` in order to make it available to the system for opening PDFs. Basically the `IntentFilter` is what Daniel described, but rather annotated directly on a class, instead of XML defined.

```
[Activity(Label = "PdfActivity")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, 
              Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, 
              DataMimeType = "application/pdf")]
public class PdfActivity : Activity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Is called when a PDF shall be opened.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="savedInstanceState">The saved instance state.</param>
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // do whatever you have to do
    }
}
```

Comment: If i launch my app using gmail pdf attachment, do i get intent action as VIEW inside my onCreate()